# Gradle: execute tasks sequentially in some task

Tags: gradle, groovy, android-gradle-plugin

I have a library, which contains 3 lib modules and 1 example module. Before deploy task I want to execute some other tasks. In command line it looks like this: `./gradlew -x:example:clean -x:example:check -x:example:uploadArchives clean check :androidLib:assembleRelease uploadArchives`.

**I want to write gradle task to execute all tasks sequentially for all modules besides example module. That I can do: `./gradlew deployAll`. How can i do it?**

I try do this:

```
task deployAll {
    doLast {
        subprojects {
             if(it.plugins.withType(com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin)) return
             it.tasks.getByName('clean').execute()
             it.tasks.getByName('check').execute()
             ...
        }
    }
}
```

But `execute()` is deprecated and it execute only first task and ignore any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dependsOn` inside of your gradle tasks to make sure your tasks run in the correct order

```
task task1{
    dependsOn task2
    //Task one code
}

task2{
    dependsOn task3
    //task 3 code
}

task3{
    //task3 code
}
```

so in this example if you call task1, first task 3 will be executed, then task2 and then finally task one, but you need only call task1.

Answer (score 1):

You can make another task and set other tasks its dependencies

```
task deployAll {
  dependsOn tasks.getByName('clean')
  dependsOn(tasks.getByName('check'))
}
```

To ensure the order add put this somewhere

```
tasks.getByName('check').mustRunAfter(tasks.getByName('clean'))
```